# Read from a file and make an associative array to use in an MSSQL update query

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have a plain text file. The below code will parse it down to an array. I want to use this in an MSSQL update statement so I think I need to make it an associative array but I am not sure how to do that because I am using `substr`.

```
<?php

$lines=array();
$fp=fopen('cit_order.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $line=fgets($fp);

    $lines[]=substr($line, 69, 5) . substr($line, 117, 2);
    $count=count($lines);
}
foreach($lines as $val) {
    print $val;
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Here is a sample of the data in the file

```
CF123412342200910286258110250 11111111 ONLY INC 47556 172206304 0000743800007438AA 0808170815170815170300000250003001 
CF123412342200910479332010335 111111FURNITURE 47569 172206305 0000319200003192AA 0808170814170814170300000350003001
```

Comment: What should be the keys in your associative array? The first `substr()`? Is it unique for each line? There's also a line of code that does nothing: `$count=count($lines);`.

Comment: yes the first substr() should be the key. I was just using the $count to see how many I have.

Comment: Show us an example of the input file

Comment: I don't know if this will work or not but 2 lines of a sample file:

Comment: CF123412342200910286258110250          11111111 ONLY INC             47556                 172206304 0000743800007438AA          0808170815170815170300000250003001                                                              
CF123412342200910479332010335          111111FURNITURE               47569                 172206305 0000319200003192AA          0808170814170814170300000350003001

Comment: the lines start with CF12341234

Comment: The output I get right now is 47556AA47569AA which in my sql update statement would look like update table set field ='AA' where id='47556'  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the first `substr()` as the key, like this:

```
$lines = [];
$fp    = fopen('cit_order.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp))
{
  $line  = fgets($fp);
  $index = substr($line, 69, 5);
  $lines[$index] = ['item1' => substr($line, 91, 10), 
                    'item2' => substr($line, 117, 2)];
}
fclose($fp);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($lines);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: When I do this my array is only the second substring.

Comment: return $lines shows  AAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA on my sample file. no key value?

Comment: @kk4iku: I changed the code, so you can see the key values as well.

Comment: How would I add a third  Item to the array substr($line, 91, 10)??